# How to work visually with a class that extends a Component in NetBeans?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel

I have a class which extends `JPanel`. I need a way to work with that visually just like a `JPanel` in NetBeans. I mean NetBeans gives me Design tab for that. What should I do?

EDIT: while you want to add new file to your project, you can see JPanel Form option, **what should I do so that I have my class which extends a component(e.g. `JPanel`) listed there**, so that I can choose that and work with that visually?

Comment: I am not getting what you mean by "visually", but i would advice you: Open a `JFrame` form, and then add `JPanel` on top of it.You can see `JPanel` on right hand side under "containers".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to create a standalone JPanel Form: navigate to a package in *Projects Explorer*, right-click it and select `New > JPanel Form`. If it is not present in the popup, select `New > Other...` and navigate to `Swing GUI Forms` category in the dialog that appears. It should be listed among `File Types`.

You cannot visually design a JPanel which was not created this way. It needs to be a JPanel Form in order for Netbeans to recognize it as an entity that can be visually designed. You can however treat it as an atomic component and add it to Netbeans by following the steps in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565313/add-jtree-checkboxtree-to-jdialog/13567816#13567816).

Comment: you mean the above steps (steps to create a standalone JPanel Form) can not be done for a class that extends `JPanel`?

Comment: @Soheil, no. If you want to visually design a component with Netbeans, you must create it with Netbeans from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about adding your new class to the NetBeans GUI builder, there is a guide on how to do this on the [NetBeans wiki](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqFormUsingCustomComponent).